# Best practice for keeping a count in database

Tags: database, postgresql, design-patterns

I would like to keep a count of every time a certain type of request is made to my server. I have two possible solutions in mind.

**1)** I can keep a table with two columns - count and id. And every time the request happens I can increment the count column. This table would only have one row.

**2)** I can have a table with only an id column and every time the request happens do an insert. Then, count the number of rows to get the count.

Would either of these methods be better (faster) than the other? Is there a best practice for doing this type of thing?

I am using Postgresql if that makes a difference.

Comment: If you truly only need the count, then store the count only and increment as you go.  Storing one row per request and counting them is more flexible, but is a high cost if all you need is a count.  Beware of speculative generality.  http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/speculative-generality

Comment: The only thing I can see is that using a single row, every operation would have to wait for the other because locking occurs at that single row level while you could insert new rows in parallel. I think sequences are supported in postgresql as well, so perhaps you should look into those.